# Split the line and add it in front of next chunk

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I convert each chunk as string. How I find the last line fed, spilt it from this chunk if does not end with closing bracket "}".  And keep that line to add it in front of the next chunk.

Code:

```
        if (rslt.Byte != null)
        {
            // How to check if content ends with "}", 
            // If no, keep that line to add it in front of next chunk.
            content = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(rslt.Byte);                           
        }
```

Comment: Try this code `if (!content.TrimEnd().EndsWith("}"))
{
    int lastBracketIndex = content.LastIndexOf("}");
    string lastLine = content.Substring(lastBracketIndex + 1);
    content = content.Substring(0, lastBracketIndex + 1);
}
`

Comment: @XiaotianYang that was very helpful. You can please add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you and I post it as answer. Hoping it can help more people.

```
if (!content.TrimEnd().EndsWith("}")) { 
    int lastBracketIndex = content.LastIndexOf("}");     
    string lastLine = content.Substring(lastBracketIndex + 1);     
    content = content.Substring(0, lastBracketIndex + 1); }
```